# Returning list of entities from BizTalk orchestration

Tags: c#, wcf, dynamics-crm-2011, biztalk, biztalk-2013

I am using BizTalk 2013 and need to retrieve data from CRM 2011 using CRM's web service. I created a service reference to CRM, created an orchestration in BizTalk and published it as a WCF service. I have a schema defining a Contact entity and when I retrieve one contact from CRM I return it as this schema ... and all is good.

My orchestration has a Request-Response port, it accepts an input of type Contact (schema) and returns the same.

The problem is when i try to return multiple Contacts. I tried creating a List in code but when I return that I get null.

Does anyone know how to achieve this? Or if there is a better way of doing it?

Thanks

Comment: return multiple? does the Contacts schema cater for that? How are you creating the message?

Comment: Hi Marvin. Good question. The schema probably doesn't ... but I don't know how to make it cater for multiple? I'm creating the message by taking a List<Contact> and serializing it into XML using XmlSerialier.Serialize()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our friends over at TechNet helped me resolve this.

Here's the [link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6456dd1b-9a8b-4bb0-a87f-1a79f60e8d25/returning-list-of-entities-from-biztalk-orchestration?forum=biztalkgeneral) in case someone has the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this you'll need:

- a new schema that caters for multiple entries of Contacts
  *An envelope schema"
- a new multipart message type with it's 1st part set to the new envelope schema
- a new request-response port type that takes a message in (what you want), and responds with the new multipart message.
- a new port that uses the new porttype
- a Construct message which creates an instance of our new message type

Now hook it all up.

Hope this helps.